# Set updated date on the active tab only

Tags: excel, vba

I have done some things in SWIFT but this is my first project in VBA.

How can I set a field on an active tab to be the modified date of the tab? I have tried to use a Sub Workbook_open () procedure but this is my first attempt at VBA and after several ours of looking, I am no closer.

Some more detail: This workbook has multiple users who are assigned a specific tab. As their manager I need to know the last time they accessed their tab so I wanted to have that entered programatically. I have a "Reference" tab that holds variables and I have an updated date cell (D2) that is referenced on the individual tabs for each user.

Here is what I have tried but the debugger doesn't get passed the first line :(

```
    `Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference")
    Dim Entry As Range: Set Entry = Sheets("Reference").Range("D2")
    Range(D2).Value = Date

    'Debug.Print MyRNG.Value

    Entry.Value = Date

    End Sub`
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Worksheet_Activate event in the sheet module. It fires when a worksheet is activated. You can write code that puts a date/time stamp into a cell somewhere in the workbook.

Remember, this code goes into the Sheet module, not a code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' this writes just the date into the current sheet's cell A1
    [A1] = Date
    ' this writes the date and time into A1 on Sheet2
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Now
End Sub
```

Be aware that this code fires when ANYONE activates the sheet. If you want to log activities of specific people only, then you need to add more refinement.